# Syncing blockchain with prune enabled

Tags: full-node, pruning

I'm syncing a node with prune enabled. Will it download the whole blockchain and then prune to my given settings after, or does it prune as it syncs?

- I'm currently `34.85%` synced
- Blockchain directory is `1.3G`
- Prune depth is `500`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will prune as it synchronizes. Disk usage shouldn't ever reach more than a few GB plus what you configured the pruning limit to.

Comment: Thanks and should I enable reindexchainstate with pruning?

Comment: No, that'll just make it start over.